# Parameterizing Environments in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, gulp, protractor

I am looking to parameterize the baseURL to run in several different environments, like "local," "dev" "test" "prod" etc. I can think of two ways of doing this.

1. Pass the baseURL param at run time.
2. Create a separate GULP task for each baseURL.

I think I want to go with option #2 but wanted to check with some others on this.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 1):

There is not much of a difference between 1. and 2., as you have to pass baseUrl param in a gulp task?

Both of them require change of code in case of new environment (that means commit-push - pull-request - find someone for code review... at least for me :) )

I think it is better to separate baseUrl from code completely into env variable:

```
onPrepare: function() {
        //load env variables for testing
        if (typeof process.env.BASE_URL !== "undefined") {
            browser.baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL;
            console.log('Base URL = ' + browser.baseUrl);
        }
```